# What does RetryingTransactionHandler work within alfresco

Tags: alfresco

Alfresco advise the programmer once you need to make a transaction into the repository to use RetryingTransactionHandler to achieve the transaction.

Can anyone give me a clarification bout that ?

specifically i'm talking about code like this

```
RetryingTransactionCallback<String> callback = new RetryingTransactionCallback<String>(){
 public String execute() throws Throwable {
     // doProcess must be invoked within user context.
 AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new RunAsWork<String>(){
 public String doWork()throws Exception{
 try {      
     if(getOperationType().equals(OperationTypes.CREATE_ORGANIZATION_OPERATION)){
 RetryingTransactionHelper txnHelper = 
     Repository.getRetryingTransactionHelper(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
     txnHelper.doInTransaction(doProcessActionCallbackOperations.CreateOrganizationCallback, false, true);
                        }
                    } catch(Throwable e){

                    }
                    return "";
                }
            }, AuthenticationUtil.getSystemUserName());
            return "";
        }
    };  
    try {
        RetryingTransactionHelper txnHelper = Repository.getRetryingTransactionHelper(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        txnHelper.doInTransaction(callback, false, true);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        if (e instanceof ReportedException == false) {
            Utils.addErrorMessage(formatErrorMessage(e), e);
        }
        ReportedException.throwIfNecessary(e);
    }
```

Also, as you are notice i use AuthenticationUtils.runAs().

So can you help me to understand different keys in this code like RetryingTransaction & AuthenticationUtils ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`RetryingTransactionHelper`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/transaction/RetryingTransactionHelper.html) ensures the `callback` you provide is executed within a transaction. Moreover, as the name suggests, if the transaction fails for some reasons (e.g. an Exception is thrown in the `callback` code that's not properly caught, or you try to change the same content in the repository concurrently from two different threads), the same transaction will be properly rolled back and re-executed ("retried") a configurable amount of times (default: 20). This is handier than manually handling transactions more often than not.

In the code you posted, you are nesting the call to `doProcessActionCallbackOperations.CreateOrganizationCallback` in two transactions (because of the last parameter of `doInTransaction` being always `true`, i.e. `requiresNew`), the outer being created before `callback` gets executed, the inner the one created within the `callback` itself. It seems to me that you could get rid of the inner transaction, but that's up to you. Transactions can be nested, even though failures in an inner transaction will most likely invalidate the whole stack of transactions.

The [`AuthenticationUtils.runAs`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/security/authentication/AuthenticationUtil.html) facility allows you to execute pieces of logic using an authority in general different from the current user. Internally, user credentials are stored as `ThreadLocal` parameters. In you case, the `AuthenticationUtil.runAs` takes care of temporarily change such `ThreadLocal` to allow the inner callback to always execute with the highest permission level (i.e. system) regardless of which user is executing the code. There are also situations where there's no logged in user currently set, e.g. within scheduled jobs. Then the `AuthenticationUtils.runAs` allows you to access the content into the repository, usually specifying `system` or `admin` users.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify a little bit more, RetryingTransactionHelper will retry the operation only if the thrown exception is of a specific kind. Mainly exceptions related to being the loser in a concurrency situation:

```
 /**
 * Exceptions that trigger retries.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
public static final Class[] RETRY_EXCEPTIONS;
static
{
    Class<?>[] coreClasses = new Class[] {
                ConcurrencyFailureException.class,
                DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class,
                StaleObjectStateException.class,
                JdbcUpdateAffectedIncorrectNumberOfRowsException.class,     // Similar to StaleObjectState
                LockAcquisitionException.class,
                ConstraintViolationException.class,
                UncategorizedSQLException.class,
                SQLException.class,
                BatchUpdateException.class,
                DataIntegrityViolationException.class,
                StaleStateException.class,
                TooManyResultsException.class,              // Expected one result but found multiple (bad key alert)
                ObjectNotFoundException.class,
                CacheException.class,                       // Usually a cache replication issue
                SQLGrammarException.class, // Actually specific to MS SQL Server 2005 - we check for this
                LockTryException.class
                };
```

I think that is enough with one of those transactions being in the exception stack, not necesarily the last one. I also think that you can avoid retries by putting an Exception that implements `org.alfresco.repo.transaction.DoNotRetryException` interface.